# How can I recover an uninstalled application on Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, data-recovery

I uninstalled Autocad on my Windows XP SP2, Without backing-up my micro code i had embedded. Is there any way to recover with the full setting? So that i will get my embedded micro code?

Comment: I doubt it, general file recovery might get bits and pieces but you've likely overwritten it. It's not like images where a random 95% of the file is good enough.

Comment: @Achu - How do you get "I can recover the application" from "I doubt it"?

Comment: @Achu - I'm glad you got lucky.  I'm still not sure how you read tobylane's comment to indicate that he thought you could do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows XP, Windows Vista or Windows 7 I would first try using the built in System Restore tool.

Go to Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools -> System Restore

There's a nice guide on the tool at http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/

You should be able to list the recovery points and they'll have names like "Install: Blah" "Uninstall: BlahBlah" and clicking on that one and carrying on through should (after a restart or so) get you back to the point before that event happened.

Comment: @Achu I just edited my answer, XP has System Restore as well and it looks and works similarly to Vista and 7.  It may still be worth a try.

Comment: @Achu No worries, I'm just glad you managed to recover it and presumably recover your Autocad licence, those things are not cheap...

Answer (score 0):

type %appdata% at the windows search bar, this takes you to a folder that contains application settings.

if you see a folder for autocad, not sure what it will be called, you may still have the settings, and if you reinstall the application if may use the appdata which was never removed.

if you don't see it there, it's probably all gone, though it may be stored somewhere else, sometimes programs leave stuff in "program files" as well.